# How does PDO::FETCH_CLASS populate the object properties before the constructor is called?

Tags: php, pdo

`PDO::FETCH_CLASS` allows to initialise a class instance with pre-populated data. It looks something like this:

```
<?php
class Bar {
    private $data = [];

    public function __construct ($is) {
        // $is === 'test'
        // $this->data === ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 1]
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }
}

$db
    ->query("SELECT `foo`, `bar` FROM `qux`;")
    ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Bar', ['test']);
```

Alternatively, one could use `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE` to call the constructor before the setter is triggered.

I am interested to know how does PDO manage to populate the Class instance through setters before the constructor is called, or more specifically, if there is a way to replicate this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to do this in PHP 5.4+ using [ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php).

Answer (score 0):

For this to work I do so:

I declare this magic method in my superclass

```
  public function __set($name, $value) {
    $method = 'set' . str_replace('_', '', $name); //If the properties have '_' and method not
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
        $val = call_user_func(array($this, $method), $value);
    }
}
```

it works very well for me